# c# Richtext box how to set text margin in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Richtext box in winform to load an rtf file.

the text align in rtf file is justify, however after loaded in richtext box it just left aligned. I wonder is there any method to set the justify align in richtext box.

And i can't find  a property to set text margin  inside the  richtextbox.is there anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The google keyword you are looking for is pfa_justify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this
http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/14/182.aspx

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130304195044/http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/14/182.aspx